# Need to return 2 remove child

Tags: javascript, while-loop, removechild

```
if ($('#notificationIco').css('display') != 'none') {
    $('#notificationIco').hide();
    var node2 = document.getElementById("bindNotification");
    var node = document.getElementById("titleNotification");
    while (node.hasChildNodes() && node2.hasChildNodes) {
        node.removeChild(node.lastChild);
        node2.removeChild(node.lastChild);
    }
    return;
}
```

i need to remove both element child is there any other way
tried the above function but not working

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to do without the context and relevant HTML, but perhaps you want: `node2.removeChild(node2.lastChild);` instead of `node2.removeChild(node.lastChild);`.

Comment: Also, in the entry criteria for `while` loop you are merely checking if `hasChildNodes` function exists for `node2`. It should instead be `node2.hasChildNodes()`.

Answer (score 0):

you're already using `jQuery` , use [.remove()](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) on the `.children` to remove the child nodes

```
if ($('#notificationIco').css('display') != 'none') {

    // ...

    $("#bindNotification").children().remove()
    $("#titleNotification").children().remove()

}
```